# ApolloClient reducer is not a function

Tags: redux, apollo, react-apollo

I am using apolloClient to send requests to a graphql Server.

However since my application use Redux I followed this document [apollo-redux](https://s3.amazonaws.com/apollo-docs-1.x/redux.html) to be able to implement apollo client with Redux.

here is my client's code:

```
const client = new ApolloClient();

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    apollo: client.reducer(),
    // others
  })
```

however the line client.reducer() fires an error

> client.reducer is not a function

How may I correct this error

Comment: what version of apollo are you using?

Comment: it is 2.1.1 - the last one

Answer (score -1):

Since `redux` is not being used as cache for Apollo starting with 2.0, you should now use the provided Apollo store:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";

const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <div>
      <h2>My first Apollo app </h2>
    </div>
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/2.0-migration.html#redux

Comment: But what about the redux store ? should I modify all my application to use the apollo store instead of the redux one ?